# Can't login to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 (dual boot with Win 7) and it was working fine. But suddenly one fine day I can't login to my user account, when I log it just flashes and then it goes back to the login screen. But the odd thing is that I can log with the guest account.

I have 2 accounts one owner account/user account and another one created for the installation of Oracle. Only the guest account can login.

From the login screen, I have pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a prompt, and login but the same thing happened there too, I entered the correct username and credentials but it flashed and goes back to the login screen.

Comment: Try to recreate the root account from the kernel level which you can do prior to booting into

Comment: This seems to be similar to http://askubuntu.com/q/223501/103256. Maybe duplicate?

Comment: I have gone through the suggestions posted in the thread , but in my case I am not able to log in the console with the user-id/password after I press Ctrl+Alt+F1/F2/F3...
Not sure how I can re-create the root account from kernel level if I can't login.
Please suggest.

Comment: Is this question still unanswered?

Answer (score 13):

This happened to me a couple of times too, this is probably because there is little space on your machine or an issue with LightDM or Xauthority but most probably xauthority. Here is what I did;

I simultaneously pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>,
Login with your user name and password, and enter following command:

```
sudo mv .Xauthority .XauthorityBak
```

then

```
sudo reboot
```

After that try again.

Comment: A reboot is probably not needed.

Comment: is the name .XauthorityBak a standard one with particular meaning or just a random one?
Also, can you just delete it with rm .Xauthority ?

Comment: I had the same problem, it happened after a reboot after some system updates. I did sudo rm /home/<username>/.Xauthority*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg
sudo reboot. This worked for me.

Comment: Awesome this worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me after a misconfiguration of bspwm, thank you

Comment: Asking for password after first command, and even after entering the right password its giving incorrect password.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.  I was installing some software to do go development, but I didn't do anything (that I know of) that would have modified permissions of the home directory (the problem previously reported).

I typed the Ctl-Alt-F1 and got the terminal login.  I tried fixing the permissions on the home directory, but that didn't fix anything.

Then I recalled adding a path command to the .profile

I removed all my changes to the .profile, and now I am fixed.

Comment: I recall modifying the .profile file when I was trying to install Oracle. I didn't had any other way to correct the issue so had to re-install the Linux all over again. :(

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me. I was able to login as myself after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. `.xsession-errors` pointed to an error in my `.bashrc`. After I removed the offending line from my `.bashrc`, I was able to login through the graphical environment.