# Stuck in Login loop in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login

I am trying to access my ubuntu 14.04 LTS account but am unable to. I login and i get the same login screen again. I have tried all the solutions present in the links : 
1.[Can't login to Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462272/cant-login-to-ubuntu-14-04) 2.[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop). I went to .Xsession-errors and saw an error which was not addressed in any of the links :

```
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/50_check_unity_support: line 7: 2731 Segmentation fault   (core dumped) /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test
```

Looking for help. I do not use dual boot. I have tried every page solution available and none have matched my error or have been able to resolve it. I have tried to log into the guest session but it leads back to the login page.

Comment: @karel- already tried all the possible ways stated. none matched or worked

Comment: You're superhuman if you tried all 37 answers in only 6 minutes and none of them worked. Don't ever touch Kryptonite.

Comment: I have tried all the solutions in the last 5 hours and then i went on to post it  as i was stuck. Indeed you should read comic books to research a phenomenon known as "presumption"

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem after removing compiz. It solved by re-installing compiz via:
 `sudo apt-get install compiz`