# Ubuntu seems locked

Tags: boot

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Windows 10 dual.

I don't know what happened, but when I tried to open ubuntu today, I only saw black screen. Then I shut the computer by force (pressing the power button) then reboot. After this moment, whenever I open Ubuntu:

- No tab on the left.
- No tab (including power) on the topright.
- No file, view etc. panel in any window.
- Alttab does not work.
- Ctrl alt t does not work.
- Alt f4 only works in closing browsers and other windows.
- Only Ctrl alt del works.

I don't want to format because I installed imporant python data and configurations which I don't want to go through again.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well when I installed some VM software. I first tried restart lightdm but didnt work so I reinstalled desktop and unity. First press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>F1</kbd> and login to your account. This step will give a terminal.

try `sudo service lightdm restart`

If lightdm fails to get back at normal :-

then Enter:- `sudo apt-get update`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

After this step and restarting the machine, when I tried to login to a guest it worked fine but when I tried to login to my account it didn't let me. If this happens to you as well press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>F1</kbd> and enter to your account. Enter the following command in the terminal and reboot:

```
sudo mv .Xauthority .XauthorityBak
```

then

```
sudo reboot
```

Taken from: [Unity Launcher and Top Panel disappeared in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-menu-bar-disappeared-in-14-04)
and
[Can't login to Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462272/cant-login-to-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: It does work in guest session but does not work for the user. Sudo mv did not work either :(