# Ubuntu 16.10 Login Loop problem

Tags: 16.10

I am not able to login in Ubuntu 16.10. Every time I logged in its redirect to same login screen. If I am clicking on guest account its not showing me my desktop. 
I tried:

1. [ubuntu 14.04 login loop problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem)
2. [Can't login to Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462272/cant-login-to-ubuntu-14-04)
3. https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+question/197479
4. https://itsfoss.com/failed-to-start-session-ubuntu-14-04/

Tried installing gnome desktop, tried creating new account still nothing is working. right now its showing me failed to start session even though Ubuntu desktop is already installed.

I have added 2 variables in `/etc/environment` file. I have removed those variables from tty1. Still its not working.

Comment: So u can login from the tty?

Comment: Yes I can Login from tty.

Comment: Well, did it just happen after installing ubuntu 16.04 or it happened after some software installation or system crash?

Did you try installing another Desktop Environment other than Gnome and Unity? Say, xfce or kde (and maybe with another display manager?)

You could try to uninstall the unity desktop while installing other DE's.

Lastly, system updates are also a great way to catchup and fix some bugs.